# Define a list within a groovy bean

Tags: groovy

I am struggling to set a List within a groovy bean.

Here is my object:

```
class TestCaseData {
    def name
    def testCaseData
}
```

where testCastData may be a String, Map or a List. I understand that if testCaseData was a map the groovy bean would look similar to this:

```
beans {
    sampleTest(TestCaseData,
            name: 'sampleTest',
            testCaseData: [
                    MyMap: [
                            key1   : 'value1',
                            key2   : 'value2'
                    ]
            ]
    )
}
```

I cannot find the proper syntax to specify a List instead of a Map however. How can I show this using the above example where 'value1', instead of a String is a List containing a Map? Not what is below but something similar.

```
beans {
        sampleTest(TestCaseData,
                name: 'sampleTest',
                testCaseData: [
                        MyMap: [
                                key1   : [aMap : [:], bMap : [:]]
                                key2   : 'value2'
                        ]
                ]
        )
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `key1: ['value1',]`?

Comment: You are correct for the simple case and I need to rephrase the question to a List that contains a Map. Once I've created a GroovyBeanApplicationContext and created the TestCaseData instance, when I check what MyMap is an instance of I get a Map (of course) but sometimes MyMap contains a List that contains more Maps.

Comment: Didn't understand. Edit the question please with input and desired output.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I want key1 to be a List and aMap to be... a map. does this make more sense?

Comment: I guess that You've solved your problem, this is a valid syntax :)

Comment: I guess then I should have asked how is there a difference between a List and a Map in a groovy bean :)

Comment: When using `def` there's no difference - it's just an object.

Comment: the syntax is `[key: value, ...]` for a map and `[:]` for an empty map; `[value, ...]` for a list, `[]` for an empty list.  yet i am still confused, what OP wants...